# Android - Creating file works on Android 5 but not in Android 6 or Above

Tags: java, android, file

I have a simple method which creates a folder inside Download Folder in Android. It works pretty fine in Android 5, but in Android 6 or above (I teste with Android 6 and 8) the folder is not created.

Did anything change?

Here is my method, as I said it is a simple create folder function. But it does not work on Android 6 or above, just in Android 5.

```
public void exportaTabelas(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
        try {
            // Query the data in the table
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);

            //File exportDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            exportDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/ENEL/");
            if (!exportDir.exists())
            {
                exportDir.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(exportDir, tableName +".csv");
            file.createNewFile();

            //CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true));

            // Write the table data to the file
            csvWriter.writeNext(cursor.getColumnNames());
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String arrStr[] = { cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1) };
                csvWriter.writeNext(arrStr);
            }

            // close cursor and writer
            cursor.close();
            csvWriter.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "ARQUIVO CSV GERADO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: for android 6 and above what `exportDir.exists()` returns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Write to File Permission on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819847/how-to-add-write-to-file-permission-on-android)

Comment: @MartinZeitler It is not. I already add this permission on XML.

Comment: @TejasPandya Returns true.

Comment: Have you [requested permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)?

Comment: @MichaelDodd I did not know about this. Thanks man, now I request permissions and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a problem with `permission`.

Android 5.1.1 and below uses install time permissions so a `<uses-permission ...>` in the `manifest` file is enough. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#install-time_requests_android_511_and_below)

But for Android over 5.1.1 you need both `<uses-permission ...>` in manifest and ask user for permission during run time. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Android Developers documentation site is your best firned!

PS: You should include any error messages you got with your question, e.g any error that got caught in a `try catch` block and logged to the Logcat in Android Studio IDE.

Comment: That is it! Thanks! Actually, in Android 6 or above, it is necessary to ask the user for the permission to write files in the device using requestPermissions method. Thanks man!